# Security Camera DC 12V , 10.5W MAX the max word it means I can use lower?

Tags: power-supply, dc

I have a Security camera that on it's box it said DC 12V , 10.5W MAX / PoE(802.3af) by the word "Max" they mean I can use lower watts ? I still didn't connect any DC's and waiting for your help can I use 12 1A, lower or higher?

Can I use 12V/1A adapter?

Thanks Saar

Comment: That 10.5 W represents a maximum power that camera will consume. So the amount of current you need to supply to it is I = P / U = 10.5 / 12 = 0.875 A ~ 1A.

Comment: Question was asked previously and closed - so he has deleted and asked exactly the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

Your 12V 1A power adapter can deliver

$$12V \times 1A = 12W$$

The minimum suitable power adapter current would seem to be

$$\frac{10.5W}{12V} = 0.875A$$

So barring any other issues, sounds like it's fine. You need to make sure you can give the device all of the power (Watts) it wants.

Comment: You helped me a lot, hope I could help you too in the future thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use 12V/1A.

When appliances mention the max power usage, they mean to say you should have a power source which can provide this much power to be on a safer side. If max power is mentioned as 10.5W and you use 12V/1A, it will work fine even though your power adapter is 12 watts. Your camera will take what's required. Your adapter won't push more power in the camera.

Consider for ex - In your home, you have the same power source - Live and Neutral wires and yet you are able to add appliances of varying power and they all work fine.

However, issue will come if you are not able to provide enough power. Let's say you had 12V 0.5A adapter. Then, your camera might not have worked because it was not getting enough power. Again, it might work as well because 10.5W is the max it needs. Maybe it needs only 5 watts - We'll know only after you have tested it.

Comment: You helped me a lot, hope I could help you too in the future thank you!!!

Comment: @SaarItzhaki - If it answered your question, select it as an answer so that other users having similar questions can use this info.

Answer (score 0):

It's about guarantees.

By saying 'max 10.5 watts', it is promising to take **no more** than 10.5 watts, at any time, and is hinting that it might take less.

If your power supply can give **at least** 10.5w, then you should have no trouble.

Just measuring what an appliance takes, and then choosing that size of power supply, does not always guarantee a happy life. Appliances can often take amounts of power that vary from time to time. If you measure it during a low power phase, and fit a supply based on that, you may have problems if it draws more from time to time. When it comes to spin up a disc, write to flash, or is asked for a higher power communication signal, it may draw extra power. The 'max power' marking on the appliance takes unexpected peaks like this into account.